VScode shows Jade related errors although the code works (!)

I have referenced the jade.jar in vscode under "Referenced libraries", and the code works. I really want to get rid of all these errors tho.


Don't post pictures of code. Just copy and paste the code in question, and/pr learn to use descriptive words and phrases to indicate what's happening; 2) If those are "errors," then why does the code work? Find better words; 3) Clean and rebuild your project: From the build menu, select Build or Rebuild menuitem.


What error message is prompted by placing the mouse over it?

@MarsAtomic I posted a screenshot in order for you guys to know where the errors are. For example when hovering over the jade imports, it woul just say that the jade package is not found. Tbh  I didnt think specifying this was necessary… you guys see where the errors are, so it is quite clear that it is a dependency issue. What else could it be? I didnt use any build manager, and still could not fix the error. The only way I could fix it was by using maven and even then I had to use a very specific pom.xml from github to actually work… the one from tilab didnt work at all.

@JialeDu "jade package not found“. I will post the answer to my own question later since I fixed it myself.

READ ME

I fixed it by using maven.
The pom.xml from tilab directly didn't work at all. I used this specific pom.xml file instead:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>tmpmaven</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.gitlab.jade-project</groupId>
      <artifactId>jade</artifactId>
      <version>master-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

